# How to open the newly created image in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Below code creates the image in the bottom of the same page. 
How to display that image into a new tab/window  instead of displaying in the same page?

```
success: function (data) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.d;
            document.body.appendChild(image);
        }
```

Comment: Use `window.open` and write into this window.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

something like:

```
success: function (data) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.d;

        var w = window.open("");
        w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
    }
```

Comment: can we do this for more then one image?

Comment: May be obvious..  But when using above in Chrome.  I get "popus were blocked..." and therefore `Cannot read property 'document' of null` :/

Comment: be advised: user cannot save image from this new window tab

Comment: Don't forget to add: w.document.close(); on the end, else the page will keep on loading. (Tested in Chrome)

Comment: Actually to the w.document.write I included a full img markup but hey it works! Thanks!

Comment: Why can't there be a function that replicates 'open image in new tab.' This works great for base64 strings where the image is centered and displayed nicely. Do you know why or how to replicate that function?

Answer (score 36):

Current suggestions were not working on chrome, I was always getting a white page, now I am using

```
const base64ImageData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
const contentType = 'image/png';

const byteCharacters = atob(base64ImageData.substr(`data:${contentType};base64,`.length));
const byteArrays = [];

for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 1024) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + 1024);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}
const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

window.open(blobUrl, '_blank');
```

Thanks to Jeremy!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/8270748

Comment: In 2022, at least for me, this is the only solution that worked in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: In 2024, this solution no longer works in my Chrome browser.

Answer (score 21):

Latest solution - works 2024-02.

Open image in new tab.

```
let data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS';
let w = window.open('about:blank');
let image = new Image();
image.src = data;
setTimeout(function(){
  w.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = image.outerHTML;
}, 0);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615423/2450431
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46510790/2450431
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798235/2450431

Comment: `document.write` [should be avoided if possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) because of its inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Sure. You could then use `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = image.outerHTML;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **document.write()** and add html page by yourself.
This option allows also to add tab title.

```
const newTab = window.open();

newTab?.document.write(
    `<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Document preview</title></head><body><img src="${base64File}" width="100px" height="100px" ></body></html>`);

newTab?.document.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hm9vb78r/)

***Updated DEMO (working in Chrome, even with pops blocked)*** - 3/3/2021

wrapping the call to `window.open` circumvents the issues detailed below.

```
document.getElementById('my_button').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  window.open("https://via.placeholder.com/150", '_blank')
});
```

*Last tested in Chrome 88 on 64 bit Windows 10.*

Comment: Inside the demo, it might be worth triggering the new window on a click event, just so it isn't blocked by most browsers as a pop-up (I thought the demo was broken for a minute before I noticed there was a blocked pop-up)

Comment: I'm getting this: "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL"

Comment: This used to work but chrome is now blocking Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL:

Comment: This is still working for me in Chrome 88  64 bit, Windows 10... However, you have to allow pop-ups (in the search bar). As @DBS suggests, running as an event handler in chrome 88 even with pop-ups blocked... Check updated demo.

Comment: Won't work if the *placeholder* is an actual data URL. [See Data_URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).