# Images are not opening in new tab. Chrome issue

Tags: angular, base64, href

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,{{image.imgname}}" target="_blank">
  <img id="myImg" src="data:image/png;base64,{{image.imgname}}"  class="actionplan-image">
</a>
```

I cant open the base64 image on new tab. Working perfectly on firefox,but apparently not on chrome

Comment: What do you get? Can you share a screenshot or something?

Comment: Its kind of a duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339593/open-base64-in-new-tab

but my query is related to angular 7

Comment: This won't work on some browsers (namely, Chrome). Are you trying to find a way to open it on a new tab? Or are you just trying to download the image?

Comment: I am trying to open it on a new tab. The client requirement is to zoom the image according to their needs. So i decided to go with opening the image in new tab. The browser has its own feature to zoom in and zoom out if an image is opened in new page.

Comment: no updates yet?