# uri is too large when opening a file in a new window

Tags: javascript

when I upload a file I want to get a string, store it in the database, and retrieve it later as a uri opening it in a new window. 
When i upload the file, i get a base64 string, and i store it in the database as LongText

```
export function getString(asset, callback) {
 if(asset) {
 const reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(asset)
 reader.onload = () => {
  callback(reader.result)
  }
 }
}
```

I retrieve it from database and try to open the uri of the file with this function:

```
openFile(string) {    
window.open(string, "_blank_")
  };
```

but i get that 414 Request - uri too large. how can i reduce the length of the uri?

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54466127/10581216

Comment: great thank you! And is there a way to set contentType so i can open images and pdf and other types?

Comment: you can replace `const byteCharacters = atob(base64ImageData.substr('data:image/png;base64,'.length));` with
`const byteCharacters = atob(base64ImageData.split(',')[1]));` and it should work for all files

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. it says "It is not possible to load the pdf file"